# mysqldump in 18.04 LTS

Tags: mysql

Trying to run mysqldump I get error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password NO) when trying to connect. This is after doing a sudo su before the mysqldump command.
I get the same thing if I don't do the sudo su and try it as a normal user, In this case is is 'user'@'localhost' instead of 'root'@'localhost'.
I don't have a .my.cnf file anywhere on the system, don't know the format of one, so I can't create one as suggested in a previous post.

Answer (score 3):

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password NO)

You did not provide a password. I would assume you need one.

```
mysqldump -u {user} -p {database} > {export.sql}
```

where you will get asked for your password. And are you sure it is root? You admin user would be my username for mysql ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen mysqldump presented with having the options for user and password so I never tried using them with the command. 
That is exactly why I was getting the 1045 errors no matter how I tried. 
Adding the -u and -p options solved my problem.